# jquery - adding listeners to generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my .js file I have a button listener that generates following:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
$('<div id="school-field'+i+'"><fieldset><a href="javascript:" id="remove'+i+'">Remove</a></fieldset></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.school');
});
```

I've been trying to generated listeners to added buttons but I can't get it to work.
I tried to use delegate on 'a' but than it's problem to find div's id. If I have the same div id for all of the generates (div id="school-field"), I do make it work but it deletes the last added elements, not the one where "remove'+i+'" was clicked. 
I also tried to define a listener inside it by doing, but it throws exception:

```
$('#remove'+i'').click(function(){
var div = document.getElementById("school-field'+i+'");
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
});
```

How can I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7 you should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because `live` and `bind` are both deprecated.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(event){
    //Your code   
});
```

<strike>You can use `live` to automatically bind new DOM elements to event listeners:
http://api.jquery.com/live/</strike>

<strike>Or you add them manually with `bind` inside the click event callback of the add button.
http://api.jquery.com/bind/</strike>

You just need to use a class or another selector which matches every element for the event listerners.

You can then use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to match the parent box.

It would look something similar to `$(this).closest('div').remove();` to remove the whole parent div.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've struggled with this one for hours... I did what you said in your last paragraph but I also added: .delegate('a','click', function(e){e.preventDefault();$(this).closest('div').remove();}); after .appendTo('.school') (In case someone needs this answer).

Answer (score 0):

try using `.on()` like this

```
$("[id^='remove']").each(function() {
  var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("remove", ""));
  var elem = $("#remove" + id);

    $("#remove" + id).on('click',function(){
      var div = document.getElementById("#school-field"+id);
      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });

});
```

Comment: Exception 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )' is thrown again. And if I do '#remove'+i and "school-field"+i, I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'' after the add buttion is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

how about using 'a[id*=remove]' as a selector for on method. eg:

```
$('first common container your a tags are stored').on('click', 'a[id*=remove]', function () {
    // your code to remove elements
});
```

it's delegated 'version' of on method with a fancy selector that matches a pattern in id attribute

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like mentioned in another answer, but use the event.currentTarget parameter that is sent to your handler.

```
$('some container you keep your links').on('click', 'a[id*=remove]', function (event) {
    $el = $(event.currentTarget).parent();
    $el.remove();
});
```

A similar functionality can be had by using live, but that method is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7
[here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html) is a great discussion of the different ways to attach events with jQuery